# The code breaks Remix for seemingly for no reason

Tags: solidity, remix

I was playing with some solidity code that reverts the array (was answering a question here on the forum). And while implementing it, I somehow broke Remix for me, it crashes the moment I ran the `reverseArray()`

NOTE: `if()` loop breaks the code.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.3;

contract RevertArray {

    function reverseArray(uint[] memory array) public pure returns(uint[] memory) {

    uint length = array.length;
    uint numberOfElements = length -1;
    uint[] memory reversed = new uint[](length);
    
    uint i = numberOfElements;
    uint j;

    while( j < length) {
        reversed[j] = array[i];
        
        // Protect from underflow error (Breaks Remix);
        if(i > 0) {
            i--;
            j++; 
        }
  
    } 

    return reversed;

    }


}
```

But a simple change in `if()` loop and Remix suddenly works:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.3;

contract RevertArray {

    function reverseArray(uint[] memory array) public pure returns(uint[] memory) {

    uint length = array.length;
    uint numberOfElements = length -1;
    uint[] memory reversed = new uint[](length);
    
    uint i = numberOfElements;
    uint j;

    while( j < length) {
        reversed[j] = array[i];
        
        // Protect from underflor error (Breaks Remix;
        if(i > 0) {
            i--;
        }
        j++; 
  
    } 

    return reversed;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you create an infinite loop on the last run of the while loop.
i is then = 0, so the loop doesn't go in the 'if' part and j isn't incremented.
so

```
while (j < length)
```

is correct and the code goes into the loop, then perform 'reversed[j] = array[i];' then finish the loop and go back to the while condition, which is still true, then again and again and again.

In your second example, you increment the 'j' anyway so you break to infinite while loop

So it's not the 'if' condition that breaks your code, it's the infinite while loop.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks,  I can't believe I haven't seen  that. I guess I  am a bit too tired.

Comment: I also often miss the obvious haha. Tomorrow is another day. Get some rest!